# Failure Rate Calculation

Tags: parallel-processing, probability, reliability

I have n identical components which are connected together in parallel system, with each having a failure rate of 0.01. Can someone point me to the equation for calculating the probability that at least 2 component will fail together?

Answer (score 1):

To model the number of failures of independent components, you can use the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).